# Python string formatting for an SQL insert statement with unknown variables

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Although there are various similar questions around this topic, I can't find one that answers my problem.
I am using pscopg to build and insert data into a postgresql database, where the insert statement exists inside a for loop, and therefore will be different each iteration.

```py
insert_string = sql.SQL(
            "INSERT INTO {region}(id, price, house_type) VALUES ({id}, {price}, {house_type})").format(
            region=sql.Literal(region),
            id=sql.Literal(str(id)),
            price=sql.Literal(price),
            house_type=sql.Literal(house_type))

cur.execute(insert_string)
```

The variables region, id, price, house_type are all defined somewhere else inside said for loop.

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "'Gorton'"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO 'Gorton'(id, price, house_typ...
                    ^
```

where 'Gorton' is the value of the variable 'region' at that  particular iteration.

From what I can see psycopg seems to be struggling with the apostrophe around Gorton, calling it a syntax error.

I have read the docs and can't figure out if sql.Literal is the correct choice here, or if I should use sql.Identifier instead?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Table names are identifiers, and quoted with double quotes in PostgreSQL.

Comment: psycopg2 will handle it if you use [`region=sql.Identifier(region)`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Identifier) instead of `sql.Literal()`. It can also handle `insert` [more effectively](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql#execute-values-from-iterator-with-page-size).

Comment: It is not `psycopg2` that is having the problem it is Postgres. In `psql` : test(5432)=> `select * from 'animals'; ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'animals'" LINE 1: select * from 'animals';` vs what it should be(if quoted) : `select * from "animals";`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver It's neither `psycopg2` nor `postgresql` that have a problem, it's [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15408938/ben). `sql.Identifier(region)` vs `sql.Literal(region)` in `psycopg2` will translate to `quote_ident(region)` vs `quote_literal(region)` in `postgresql`, which ends up causing the `"Gorton"` vs `'Gorton'` problem.

Comment: @Zegarek 1) I was replying to Ben's comment in the question: *"From what I can see psycopg seems to be struggling with the apostrophe around Gorton, calling it a syntax error."* 2) Postgres was having a problem as a literal was being used where an identifier was needed. If there was no problem there would be no error.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Sorry, I didn't see that. I meant it as a joke reference to [PEBMAC error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error). I agree that if PostgreSQL didn't have a problem, psycopg2 wouldn't have a problem, neither would Ben, nor would we.